# ASP.NET Session reset? in IE, not in FF

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox, session

Thanks in advance for any assistance anyone can provide with this torturous issue.

I have an ASP.NET website built against framework 3.5SP1 in VS2010. This (essentially the) same website has been deployed several times on several servers without this issue - however they were built with VS2008. The server is 2003 IIS 6.

The application loads ok initially - and in order to do so it requires a session variable be set - otherwise you get no map. If you drag a box on the map it should zoom in - and in Firefox this happens.

Now the issue: In IE (6 or 8, haven't been able to test 7) when you drag a box on the map you get the Processing graphic and then a response from the server indicating that things went wrong because what's in the session is not acceptable.

Yes, I know that's not very clear, and if it turns out that we need more info I'll provide it, but it a complex flow.

But here's what I am wondering: Has anyone experienced a situation in which IIS treats IE differently than FF in terms of the Session? If so, how to debug, links to white-papers, etc...

Please let me know if you need any more information to think through this.

And again, thanks.

**Edit to add Request headers.**

Initial Request (IE):

```
POST /aogconline/MapControl.aspx?Config=gwpc_ar.xml HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, */*
Referer: http://170.94.97.202/aogconline/MapStart.aspx?Config=gwpc_ar.xml
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 170.94.97.202
Content-Length: 35
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0kabez45vpfg5s45iqqfzb45
```

Subsequent Request (IE):

```
POST /aogconline/MapControl.aspx HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, */*
Referer: http://170.94.97.202/aogconline/MapControl.aspx?Config=gwpc_ar.xml
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 170.94.97.202
Content-Length: 39905
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=0kabez45vpfg5s45iqqfzb45
```

Initial Request (FF):

```
POST /aogconline/MapControl.aspx?Config=gwpc_ar.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: 170.94.97.202
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://170.94.97.202/aogconline/MapStart.aspx?Config=gwpc_ar.xml
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=iayvjh55z04mij55jjb0ir45
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 35
```

Subsequent Request (FF):

```
POST /aogconline/MapControl.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: 170.94.97.202
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://170.94.97.202/aogconline/MapControl.aspx?Config=gwpc_ar.xml
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=iayvjh55z04mij55jjb0ir45
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 39900
```

Comment: Have u tried clearing cache,...? Might be useful to put a dump of the request (including headers)

Comment: I should also mention that there are Response.Redirect calls used. Perhaps this could affect something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an errant bit of code that was abandoning the session. Thanks to all who viewed and  @Aliostad for answering.

Comment: This should've been affecting all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

As you have guessed, your problem seems to be the Response.Redirect. What is the URL of redirection? This causes an object moved and depending on the URL, cookie's might not be sent - including session causing session reset.

What is your redirect URL and what is your original URL? Do they have the same root?

Use Fiddler to check if the ASP.NET session cookie is sent to the server after `Response.Redirect`.

Comment: Exactly, that's where I went, unfortunately (for ease of fixing) the session cookie is sent after redirection and is the same. You can see this in the above requests.

Comment: Do you have to use Response.Redirect? Can you not use Server.Transfer that everything is done on the server?

Comment: Perhaps, but what I am really looking for is why IE different than FF?